# OpenVPN drop internet connection

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn

I'm making a VPN connection with Network Manager on Linux Mint. I connect to VPN, after 20 minutes maybe 30 minutes (sometimes, i never connect to the internet)my internet connection drops and I can't even ping 8.8.8.8. But I can connect to each port of the VPN server. I have no problems with another Linux Mint machine with the same settings. How can I fix this or where should I look?

Answer (score 0):

Could be an MTU issue, you could try setting lower values.
To determine the optimal MTU value, ping the server by using ping -M do -s {size} server on linux.

Or using: ping -f -l {size} server on Windows.

Remove brackets.

Vary size to find the optimal value. Start out with 1472, as that is default. If the MTU needs to be lowered, then lower it on both ends of the connection.

Another thing would to check which protocol you are connecting through. If you are using UDP, try TCP instead. Also, copy and paste your log message from OpenVPN. That would help narrow down what your issue might be.

Lastly, make sure you have the most recent version of OpenVPN and the most recent Windows TAP driver. That can cause wonky things to happen.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. I try different MTU sizes. But it did not work. I use the latest version of OpenVPN.